# SQL Standard: Window function on Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've needed to figure out what the following line says as a part of a code that tracks a funnel on a website. I haven't seen the function WINDOW written like that. I am using SQL standard on Google BigQuery. Do you know what this means?

```
 WINDOW
session_hits AS (PARTITION BY fullvisitorId, visitId ORDER BY hits.hitNumber)
```

There are no comments on the code, so sometimes it's difficult to what it does.

Thanks!

Comment: You should review any general documentation on what `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` do in the context of a window.

Comment: Bq gives you ability to create WINDOW which can  then be used with over clause in select stmt. So you can create one window and use with different functions for eg count, sum, rank, dense rank, row_number, max.. Min etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, I am not using the over clause in this case.

Comment: how about simply read documentation for [WINDOW clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#window_clause)? :o)